# Python Tkinter Resize the window dynamic to contents

Tags: python, tkinter

I've been browsing around and im wanting to dynamically resize an active Tkinter window, based upon whats typed in a label.

[image]

But how can I then dynamically resize this window based upon the amount of data returned, example below.

[image]

My Current Tkinter setup;

```
#Create Window
root = Tk()

root.title("Customer Details")
#Resize Window
root.geometry("375x125+300+300")
#Creste Element frames
TopFrame = Frame(root)
TopFrame.pack()
MiddleFrame = Frame(root)
MiddleFrame.pack()

#Track load elements
View = Button(TopFrame, text='View',command=View, padx=15)
Cust = Entry(TopFrame, text="Waiting..", fg="black", justify='center')
View.pack(pady=5, fill=BOTH, side=RIGHT)
Cust.pack(side=LEFT)

CurrentStatus = Label(MiddleFrame, text="Waiting for customer!", fg="black", justify='left')
CurrentStatus.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)

#Loop Window to make sure it doesn't disappear
root.mainloop()
```

Any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: use `lower_case` names for variables (like `top_frame`) to make code more readable. We use `CamelCase` names only for classes (like `Button`, `Entry`, `Label`). See: [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)